# How to setup a VLAN switch with Hyper-V virtual external switch?

Tags: networking, hyper-v, windows-server-2016, vlan, vswitch

I currently have Windows Server setup with one physical ethernet port (eth0) as an external VLAN trunk connected to a Hyper-V virtual external switch for VMs to share with the host. The host uses specifically VLAN1 while the virtual switch allows VMs to use and share from VLAN1 to VLAN3.

Now I want to connect another physical ethernet port (eth1) to the same virtual switch or something similar so I can connect an external network device to it (eth1) and have the communication be able to pass through the other physical external VLAN trunk (eth0).

Typically, it would be a much easier task to do if it was on a router configuration, but I can't figure how I go about doing the same thing on Windows. The configuration for network adapters in the current network setup confused me, let alone the new network configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you need routing on Windows Server, you can install RRAS. Using Powershell,

```perl
Install-WindowsFeature RemoteAccess
```

(reboot is needed)

If you need the Admin Tool for it (on the same server or somewhere else):

```
Install-WindowsFeature RSAT-RemoteAccess-PowerShell
```

The routing component:

```
Install-WindowsFeature Routing
```

Then from Server Manager's tools, you can start Routing and remote access and configure the server for LAN routing.

Comment: I did some readings on RRAS and installed and setup LAN routing on the server; however, I am stuck now. It seems there is no option to create a VLAN switch. I can only create a static route, NAT, DHCP Relay Agent, and IGMP Router and Proxy. I can see that maybe I can create a NAT or a static route between eth0 and eth1, but I don't think it can be routed down properly out the VLAN trunk on eth0 since it is tagged on the virtual switch as VLAN1 for the host and I want eth1 to be tagged as VLAN2. What do I do after this part?